# How to get the system language or the language that was selected when Mac OS X was installed

Tags: macos, language, cocoa

I know the common `sudo languagesetup` to set the system language. Does someone know how to get the system language or the language that was selected when Mac OS X was installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The left part of `osascript -e 'user locale of (get system info)'` is the language selected in Setup Assistant (I think).

The language at the top of the list in the Language & Text preferences should be the second line of `defaults read -g AppleLanguages`.

Comment: osascript -e 'user locale of (get system info)' is returning the locale as same as following code gives   NSLocale *locale;
    locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];   
    NSLog(@"Current locale Identifier %@",[locale localeIdentifier]);                                         This is the system language for the currently logged in user right?not the default system language.

Comment: @Akbar is correct: add a language in the prefpane, make it go at the top, run the osascript command and witness the change.